# Unity 2D joystick movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Hi, I'm trying to do some joystick movement and when the character goes left the character sprites flip Face to left. It's actually look like working but it's not. When the character crosses the left side of the red line, it turns to the left, when it moves to the right side, it turns to the right. So how can i fix this? [image]   **
**My codes;**

```
float horizontal;
public float Speed;

public Joystick joystick;
Rigidbody2D rb;
bool facingRight = true;
private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    
    horizontal = joystick.Horizontal;
    if (horizontal != 0)
    {
        //transform.up = new Vector3(horizontal * Speed, 0, 0);
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(horizontal, 0, 0)*Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        

    }
    if (gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().transform.position.x < 0 && facingRight)  
    {
        flipFace();
    }
    else if (gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().transform.position.x > 0 && !facingRight)
    {
        flipFace();
    }

}

void flipFace()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight; 
    Vector3 tempLocalScale = transform.localScale;
    tempLocalScale.x *= -1; 
    transform.localScale = tempLocalScale; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking `transform.position.x`, you should check your movement or your input. You can flipFace when velocity is > 0 or < 0, which means if you are actually going left or right. Check velocity instead of position.

Comment: Is that what you mean `rb.velocity.x`  or `gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x` I tried both but didn't work. How can i get the joystick inputs?

Comment: Okay İ figure it out you were right I should have used velocity. Its not working  because im not using velocity. There is no have velocity in the characters rigidbody so i changed the code like that(codes in the answer). And thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Its not working because im not using velocity. There is no have velocity in the characters rigidbody so i changed the code like that:**

```
if (horizontal != 0)
        {
            //transform.up = new Vector3(horizontal * Speed, 0, 0);
            //transform.Translate(new Vector3(horizontal, 0, 0)*Speed * Time.deltaTime);
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(horizontal * Speed, rb.velocity.y);


        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
        if (rb.velocity.x < 0 && facingRight) // < 0 ise sola gidiyor demektir  > 0 is sağa gidiyor demektir
        {
            flipFace();
        }
        else if (rb.velocity.x > 0 && !facingRight)
        {
            flipFace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code in void Update

```
private bool ConFisicas=true;
float horizontal;

void start()   { }


   horizontal = joystick.Horizontal;
    if (ConFisicas)
    {
      


        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, body.velocity.y);
        Debug.Log(horizontal);
        //transform.up = new Vector3(horizontal * speed, 0, 0);
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(horizontal, 0, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (horizontal > 0 || horizontal < 0)
            anim.SetBool("isMove", true);
        else
            anim.SetBool("isMove", false);

    }
    if (facingRight == false && horizontal > 0)
    {
        Flip();

    }
    else if (facingRight == true && horizontal < 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
```

Comment: As it stands you have an empty `start()` function. Is that a cut and paste error?

Comment: Not a mistake, just enter the code you need and the second update, enter my code